# Mysql data encryption

Tags: php, android, mysql, encryption, aes

I have a mobile app that sends data to the MySQL database using PHP. I want to use  AES_ENCRYPT function in the PHP file to encrypt my data at the MySQL server. I do not have much experience in data encryption.

Is this method will protecting my data? If not what other methods can I use to secure my data?

I read a tutorial saying the key will be stored in the PHP file, is this method secure and is there any way I can protect my key from being hacked?

Comment: You're getting a little ahead of yourself.  First define **exactly** what attack you want to protect yourself from - there is no point implementing a bunch of security measures against an attack that may not even exist!

Comment: You could make a stored procedure and have the key in there. Then the key wouldn't live in your PHP. This isn't a PHP question really. Nor an android question. You should go into more detail, might be more suited for https://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @user3783243 Storing the key on the MySQL server is arguably worse - a breach there gives the attacker both the key and the ciphertext, whereas storing the key on the PHP server (provided they're two isolated servers) does not.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark A breach of the PHP would give the credentials to the mysql server. If that is compromised so is the mysql.

Comment: @user3783243 Yep - but a breach of only the MySQL server would not expose the key if it is stored on the PHP server.  Under your suggestion, however, breaching the MySQL would expose both the ciphertext and the key.  Which is worse!

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark PHP would expose both as well, which is the same? The mysql breach would depend on which user was breached, and what the permissions were.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm saying.  I was never talking about a PHP breach.  Only a MySQL breach - and I'm saying it is far better for the key to not be on the MySQL server if that breach happens!

Comment: Thank you all, I already said that I have less knowledge in information security, @LukeJoshuaPark what I am doing, I am collecting data from participants for a research , I and I need to protect the privacy of this information, what I have been told is that I am relying on the security level that the university servers have, and I have to encrypt the data to protect the participants information. one tutorial explained the use of the aes_encrypt function, and I wanted to know if that will suit my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question ultimately leads back to key management - the key has to be stored **somewhere**.  Where you store the key depends on the amount of security required.

In your scenario (you mention university), I would argue that storing the key on your PHP server (*not* the database server) would be "enough".

Protection of the key then comes back to how well protected that PHP server is.

I recommend you do your encryption in your PHP code, not using `AES_ENCRYPT` - this prevents the database server ever knowing what the key is and means that a breach to the database server will not expose any information.

You may also be interested in [this repository](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) that demonstrates how to securely encrypt and decrypt data in PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful.